# Regex matches, gives 1 result

Tags: c#, regex

So i've searched all of the internet, and i can't find a working solution to my problem.

I have a HTML table

```
<tr>something</tr>
<tr class="even detailed">Something</tr>
<tr class="odd detailed">something</tr>
// and so on
```

Now i will all the content of the tr's with and even or odd class. but i only get 1 result. my C# code is:

```
pattern = @"<tr class=""(even|odd) detailed"">(.*)</tr>";
var matches = Regex.Matches(Contents, pattern, RegexOptions.Singleline);
```

I've tried lots of things, but it doesn't seem to work. With this i only get 1 result.

Comment: You should explore HTML 5 data attributes.  jQuery selectors and data attributes are SO much cleaner than regex.

Comment: [You cannot use regex to parse HTML](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6751105/why-its-not-possible-to-use-regex-to-parse-html-xml-a-formal-explanation-in-la). Find an HTML parsing library for C#.

Comment: Only Chuck Norris has been able to successfully parse HTML using RegEx.

Comment: @icemanind And see, what it was worth: It blew out his brain and now he has to do [this](http://www.meetthenra.org/nra-member/chuck-norris) - so Regex on HTML is the only Nemesis for Chuck Norris.

Comment: Interesting. I didn't think Chuck Norris had a Kryptonite counterpart

Comment: You must only add a "?" after your "*" quantifier.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Consider the following Regex...

```
(?<=\<tr.*?(even|odd).*?\>).*?(?=\<)
```

Good Luck!

Answer (score 0):

Regular expressions, by default, follow the "leftmost-longest" rule, which is to say, that they are greedy and will find the leftmost, longest possible match. Your `.*` rule happilay (ecstacticly, even) consumes the all the `</tr>` elements save the last, along with all the `<tr>` elements save the first, leaving you with just one match.

Further, as @TimS noted, HTML is not a "regular" language in the sense of "regular expressions".

Comment: `.*?` makes it non-greedy, usually.

Answer (score 0):

It is better solution to use a html parser. but if you really want to use a regex, this is a solution

regex:

```
<tr\s+class="(even|odd)\s+detailed">(.*?)</tr>
```

the code

```
string strRegex = @"<tr\s+class="(even|odd)\s+detailed">(.*?)</tr>";
RegexOptions myRegexOptions = RegexOptions.None;
Regex myRegex = new Regex(strRegex, myRegexOptions);
string strTargetString = @"<tr>something</tr>" + "\n" + @"<tr class=""even detailed"">Something</tr>" + "\n" + @"<tr class=""odd detailed"">something</tr>" + "\n" + @"// and so on";

foreach (Match myMatch in myRegex.Matches(strTargetString))
{
  if (myMatch.Success)
  {
    // Add your code here
  }
}
```